# method is giving an error with API Call

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm writing a node js function for alexa and in that there is an API call that has to be made. if this is a plain text, I get the response else it gives me error as below.

```
feedback is not a function\nStacktrace:\n====================\nTypeError: feedback is not a function\n
```

here is my code.

```
var apiServices = require('./apiServices.js');
feedback();
    var feedback = () => {
        if (!session.attributes.pin) {
            response.speechText = "Absolutely, I can help with that. What is the PIN Number??";
            response.repromptText = "What is the PIN Number??";
            response.shouldEndSession = false;
            response.done();
        } else {

            apiServices.getCaseStatus("status", function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data.length);
                    response.speechText = `you have total ${data.length} pending cases`;
                    response.repromptText = " Is there anything else that I can Help you with?";
                    response.shouldEndSession = false;
                    session.attributes.shouldLoop = true;
                    response.done();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

here instead of making an API Call in `else`, if i use text as below.

```
else {
     response.speechText = `you have total ${data.length} pending cases`;
      response.repromptText = " Is there anything else that I can Help you with?";
     response.shouldEndSession = false;
     session.attributes.shouldLoop = true;
     response.done();
     }
```

it is working fine. please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to venture to guess that in this same file you have a thing called `feedback` defined elsewhere.  That definition is being used instead of the function.  To fix this, swap the order so you are calling the function *after* defining.  Probably also a good idea to adjust variable names so you aren't using the same name for unrelated things.

Comment: Thanks my friend. The issue was with the reordering :)